# Programmatically invoke garbage collector

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

Is there a way to invoke the garbage collector on a specific object within managed memory from an application?

e.g. (in pseudo-code)

```
Read myString from file;
perform arbitrary operation on myString;
invoke garbage-collector to remove myString
```

Comment: Smells funny. Any particular reason why you want this to happen explicitly rather than automatically?

Comment: Doesn't smell funny if the developer is a beginner and doesn't realise that GC does not need to be explicitly called.  We all went through that phase when we wanted to call `GC.Collect()`.

Comment: Yep - the string could contain a password which I don't to remain for long in managed memory. I know there are more sensible and secure ways to do this, but I was curious as to whether there was a way to do this.

Comment: @Rick - If you're worried about security, you might ask a different question related to storing passwords in memory - you might get some helpful answers.

Comment: That was supposed to be `SecureString`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx

Comment: I think the SecureString approach is better. Or use C++(which is probably better here if you know what you're doing).

Comment: Why worry about securing the string in memory when you're reading the password from a file?

Comment: @Peter J the password won't actually be read from a file but will be stored as an encrypted value in a database and then decrypted at runtime... I just said that it would be read from a file to avoid a debate about how secure my method of acquiring the string was

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GC.Collect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) it'll tell it to run a collection. But, it won't collect specific objects. The GC is non-deterministic in relation to which objects are collected or not and when.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't want it to be deterministic. The GC knows more than you do about when to collect your garbage. The only exception is when your object holds native resources or disposable objects, in which case you should be sure to implement IDisposable.

Comment: @Mark: However, it's better to control this via AddMemoryPressure/RemoveMemoryPressure, and still not call GC.Collect().  If you're tracking non-managed memory resources, AddMemoryPressure is the way to let the GC "know" about it - it's still better to let it decide.

Answer (score 5):

No, and it wouldn't have an effect in any case:

Think about it this way.  Say you had a custom class, `MyBigMemoryClass`, that you wanted to collect an instance of - you'd have to have some way to pass a reference of that to the garbage collector.  In a theoretical world, it would be something like:

```
// Not valid code!
MyBigMemoryClass instance = GetMyInstance();
GC.CollectObject(instance);
```

However, at this point, you still have a reference to the instance of your class in the `instance` variable, so the **object is still rooted, and not a candidate for garbage collection**.  The GC would see that its rooted, and leave it be.

The closest you can do is to unroot your object instance, and then have the garbage collector try to collect everything:

```
MyBigMemoryClass instance = GetMyInstance();
// Do something with instance
instance = null; // Unroot this, so there are (hopefully) no references to it left
GC.Collect(); // Collect everything
```

That being said, this is typically a very bad idea.  It's much better to never call the garbage collector, and allow it to manage the memory for you.  There are very few exceptions to this, mostly when working with native code, and those exceptions are typically handled better by using [GC.AddMemoryPressure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.addmemorypressure.aspx) and [GC.RemoveMemoryPressure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.removememorypressure.aspx).

Comment: @Reed: Could you please look at my comments & let me know, if it makes sense, at all?

Comment: @Reed: I am reading this http://reedcopsey.com/2009/05/01/idisposable-part-5-using-idisposable-classes-in-c/. So, what happens to a string member inside the LoggingLicenseGenerator, when you dispose it?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.  It sits there, until LoggingLicenseGenerator is unrooted, which causes the string to be unrooted.  If Dispose set the string reference to null, it ~might~ get collected before that, but that's not really the purpose behind dispose.

Comment: Calling instance.Dispose() does not unroot instance, though.  You'd have to do instance = null;, and also make sure nothing else has a reference to instance - then it (and it's encapsulated string) will be eligable for GC.

Comment: @Reed: Sir, thats what I meant when I say - wrap it inside a class that implements IDisposable. I know it is crude and hence I said towards the end, don't worry about it.

Comment: @Reed: "Calling instance.Dispose() does not unroot instance". I suppose, if you have reference (to an instance of class that implements IDisposable) & when you call Dispose(); on one of the reference, rest of the references will fail (ofcourse, after the GC runs and the IDisposable instance is collected) with ObjectDispoedException, if my understanding is right.

Comment: Nope.  It's never possible to raise ObjectDisposedException on an object after GC - because you can't have a reference to it anymore (so no way to trigger that).

Comment: @Reed: I think I didn't explain myself well. Assume that you have an instance of a StringReader class & you have another variable referencing it. Once you are done using it, you call Dispose on one of the instance variable. The other reference doesn't know that it was made eligible for collection. Will the runtime not raise "ObjectDisposedException" when one tries to access the members of the "other" instance?

Comment: @Reed: Surprisingly, StringReader class doesn't wrap any unmanaged resources & implements IDisposable. I am confused as to what is the right thing here?

Comment: There are many cases like this - They are often used for factored types (you can keep reading my series to see this), but in this case, it's because TextReader implements IDiposable (StringReader's base class) so that derived, specific classes which "read" from native resources will work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Collect method on the Garbage collector, but it should be avoided 99.999% of the time for performance reasons.  It's hard to predict the right time to clean up those objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.collect.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Currently* there is no managed API to invoke the GC on a specific object.

at Dec 17, 2009: *.NET 3.5 SP1* and *.NET 4.0 Beta 2* do not have it.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other wonderful answers...

Be aware that it is *very* unlikely you need to actually call GC.Collect() yourself.  The garbage collector is very smart and knows when to do its business.  See [Scott Holden's blog post about GC](http://blogs.msdn.com/scottholden/archive/2004/12/28/339733.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge it's not possible to be this specific with collection with C#.

It's often cited as one of the cons of C# compared to C/C++.

That said, it would be interesting to know why you want to do this, it does sounds a little like premature performance work.  Lots of great advice against this in interesting book I'm reading now, "Coders at Work".

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need it, if it is a string.
It will be collected, when you make sure that there are no references hanging on to it.

To force garbage collection, you could create a class that implements `IDisposable` interface, provide necessary implementation, use that class in the code & release it by calling `Dispose` on it.

e.g.

```
using (WrapsTheStringAndIsDisposable blah = new WrapsTheStringAndIsDisposable())
{
  .....
}
```

I would go on to say, don't worry about it.

Comment: But how would you collect the string *within* that class?  Sure, you could dispose classes that implement `IDisposable` but strings are disposable that way.  I agree with your answer in principle, but it won't work for strings.

Comment: IDisposable has absolutely nothing to do with managed memory, such as a string.  Disposing of a class DOES NOT FREE MEMORY.

Comment: @Reed Copsey - Exactly...  With strings you're at the mercy of the garbage collector.

Comment: @Reed: I know that Disposing a class does not free memory. It makes the instance eligible for collection. Also, you are incorrect in saying "IDisposable has absolutely nothing to do with managed memory". IDisposable doesn't put restrictions (on the class that implement it) to use unmanaged resources.

Comment: @Reed: What happens to classes that implement IDisposable and hold string instance inside it? Are they not garbage collected, when dispose is called on the wrapper class instance?

Comment: @Reed: To your answer "The closest you can do is to unroot your object instance, and then have the garbage collector try to collect everything" - Isn't this what I say already by "It will be collected, when you make sure that there are no references hanging on to it."?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: It actually does not have anything to do with garbage collection whatsoever.  Calling Dispose() does not (typically) make a string elegable for GC.  I recommend reading: http://reedcopsey.com/2009/03/20/idisposable-the-oft-misunderstood-and-misused-interface/

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Yes.  Unrooting is making sure there is nothing hanging to it - but that has nothing to do with IDisposable.  You're mixing two very different things togehter (memory management and IDisposable, which is about resource, and typically native resource, management).