# System.IO.File::Move fails, The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: axapta, x++, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm getting the error "*System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process*" while trying to move a file i just created myself in the code, while running the code as batch. I have no problems running it as a client. I have tried Googelling and some of the suggestions are incl. below but uncommentted since it did not work. (filenameOutTemp is the one i can't access)

```
    ...
    asciiIoOut   = new AsciiIo(filenameOutTemp, #io_append);
    asciiIoOut.outFieldDelimiter(#fieldDelimiter);      

    if (createFile)
        {
            // Replace the vend account from DDD with local:
            record = conpoke(record, colVendDDD, vendSetupDDD.VendAccount);
            asciiIoOut.writeExp(record);
        }
    }

    //CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
    asciiIoOut.finalize();
    asciiIoOut = null;


    //Move from temp folder to vender item folder:
    fshVendTable = RetailVendTable::find(vendSetupDDD.VendAccount);
    filenameOut  = fshVendTable.filePathImport(VendorFileImportPath::Items);
    filenameOut += #filePathSeperator + substr(inventImportFiles.Filename,1, strLen(inventImportFiles.Filename) - 4 );
    filenameOut += #spacer + #item + #spacer + filenameDate + #spacer + filenameTime + #csv;

    //new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop).assert(); // get dll interop permission
    try {
        System.IO.File::Move(filenameOutTemp, filenameOut);
    }
    catch(Exception::Error) {
         warning("move failed");
    }
```

hope someone can please help :)

Comment: Similar to my very own problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637619/move-a-file-ax2012

Comment: :( If all else fails, restart the AOS, try instanciating a System.Diagnostics.Process and execute a 'move' command 
The very last resort.

Comment: why are your permissions commented out?

Answer (score 1):

The code in batch is executed by .Net, which do not have deterministic garbage collection.

This is a problem as AsciiIo files are closed when garbage collecting the AsciiIo object!

You *may* solve the problem by [programatically invoking the garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923158/programatically-invoke-garbage-collector).
Only do this in batch!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a static server method much like `WinAPIServer::CopyFile(...)` and then calling that method when executing the batch?